# TabControl loops back to the first tab. Can this be prevented?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

When a WPF TabControl has focus, the arrow-keys can be used to switch the active tab. However, after I reach the final tab, it loops back to the first tab again. I'd like to prevent this, so that users get a more should-be-done-in-this-order kind of feel to the application.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this rather heavy-handed approach using the SelectionChanged event. It does the job except that the dotted-line focus indicator still gets shown on the "loginTab" entry even though the TabControl continues to have the "lastTab" displayed as intended. The Focus() call doesn't keep focus on the last tab.

```
    private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Source == wizardTabs && e.RemovedItems.Count != 0 && e.AddedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            TabItem fromItem = e.RemovedItems[0] as TabItem;
            TabItem toItem = e.AddedItems[0] as TabItem;

            if (fromItem.Name == "lastTab" && toItem.Name == "firstTab")
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                wizardTabs.SelectedItem = fromItem;
                fromItem.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to edit this answer and remove the question part to prevent it from being removed. Create a new question on that particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the steps need to be done in a specific order, do not use a tab control.

You should probably use a wizard interface in that situation.

If, on the other hand, the steps do not need to be done in a specific order, I don't know why you would want to give the users that impression.

Comment: Since there's no official "wizard control", most web sites suggest that users create their own wizard to work the way they want. That's what I'm trying to do, and as part of that, I'd like to prevent the looping from the last tab to the first. That's why. Also, my app isn't an official wizard--users may want to jump between tabs to enter the required information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the attached property `KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation` on the `TabControl` to `Once`?